# Call Object#send when a class override it

Tags: ruby, overriding

I've a class `MyServer < UNIXServer` that inherits from `UNIXServer`.

I need to call the [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) method on its object, but I don't know how to call it because `UNIXServer` override it with [this method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/BasicSocket.html#method-i-send). Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc say:

> You can use `__send__` if the name send clashes with an existing method
>   in obj.

Answer (score -1):

I you want to have the original `send` method you can create an alias in the `Object` class.

```
# Opening the `Object` class
# and aliasing the original `send
Object.class_eval do
  alias_method :original_send, :send
end
```

After doing this you can call `original_send` in an `MyServer` instance and it behaves like the original `send` method.

If this is abstract for you take a look into [Metaprogramming in Ruby](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/2-metaprogramming-ruby/chapters/32-introduction-to-metaprogramming/lessons/75-being-meta).

---

As Jörg W Mittag and @pioz already said you can also use the `__send__` method. [Docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/__send__)